# scala for yield says type mismatch

Tags: scala

Eclipse throws an exception:

```
type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[Any] required: scala.concurrent.Future[Boolean]
```

I am newer in scala , so I only need to return a boolean whether extractWord result is present or not..

What is my problem on this code? I'm misconceiving something...

```
override def checkAccessAuthorized(implicit request: RequestHeader, context: ExecutionContext,sessionTimeoutInSeconds: Int): Future[Boolean] = {

      (for {
        word <- extractWord
      } yield for {
            Some(userId) <- cacheUtils.get(word)
            _ = cacheUtils.prolongTimeout(word, sessionTimeoutInSeconds)
        } yield {
         Future.successful(true)
      }).getOrElse {
        Future.successful(false)
      }
}
```

The header for the prolongTimeout method is:

```
def prolongTimeout(word: AuthenticityWord, timeoutInSeconds: Int)(implicit request: RequestHeader, context: ExecutionContext) : Unit
```

Comment: What is the type of extractWord?

Comment: Please read about creating a good [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question.

Comment: what happens when you compile directly with sbt (or whatever you might be using)?

Comment: probably what you want is `userId <- cacheUtils.get(word)` (dropping the Some)